# Como encontrar valor mais próximo em uma array?

Tags: javascript, array

```
var dados=[0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 4.0, 4.75, 5.0, 5.7, 6.0, 6.2, 6.5, 7.0, 7.1, 7.5, 8.0];
var DadoMaisPertoDe = 3.8; 
//preciso encontrar o valor 4.0

//outra demanda
//dado o valor encontrado acima (4.0)
//preciso achar dois valores acima e dois abaixo desse valor, dado um intervalo minimo
I=1.0; //intervalo minimo
//preciso achar  [2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0] //lembrando q parte de 4.00 encontrado antes
I=1.5;
//preciso achar  [1.0, 2.5, 5.7, 7.5]
```

1. Como faço para encontrar o valor mais próximo em um array?
2. Como faria para encontrar alem desse valor, os dois valores mais próximos  do valor que encontrei acima, mas com um intervalo mínimo  (I)?

desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Editado:
Se mais alguém vir a precisar de ajuda com algo parecido, encontrei a solução aqui: http://jsfromhell.com/pt/array/nearest-number

Answer (score 2):

Como isso tem cara de trabalho de faculdade, não farei, apenas mostrarei como fazer.

Dando uma rápida pesquisada, encontrei o seguinte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49436218/5565024

Como pode ver, ele diz que seguindo a premissa de que não sabia se podia ordenar o array, ele fez dessa forma ai. Porém, independente se não deseja mudar a ordem do array atual, acredito que seria mais fácil ordenar o array, e ir incrementando ou decrementando num loop para encontrar os valores próximos.

Portanto, pode seguir o outro exemplo em que for ordenado (sort) o array: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49436066/5565024

Com isso, basta ir criando a lógica e ir salvando em variáveis e comparando, o mais próximo até conseguir os dois antes e depois do valor desejado e de acordo com o intervalo mínimo.

Após conseguir, poste a resposta aqui para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: grato pelo retorno. O array, já estará sempre ordenado em ordem crescente e será algumas vezes grande, com cerca de 700 a 1000 elementos. Não é de faculdade, faço pra atender meu as necessidade de meu próprio site, não sou programador em js. mas o o google e o stackoverflow, me viro como posso. Normalmente acho algo, mas nesse caso não tinha achado nada.

Comment: Creio q com esse exemplo q passou eu consigo chegar lá. Não imaginei isso possível com reduce. Tinha imaginado com loops, mas creio q poderia ficar mto pesado pra necessidade.

Comment: Comece a desenvolver o script, e caso esbarrar em algum problema, peça ajuda aqui no stack. Como não programa em JS, provavelmente não conhece o lodash. Dá uma pesquisada a respeito, pode ser que o ajude a fazer o script mais facilmente. =]